# Incorrect order for layouts inside a TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

My code is as below and the result is like in the image. Any idea how to move the "test" to the back and "check", "session", "set" to in front? I thought the layout will follow the sequence to display, I have no idea why it doesn't follow the sequence and moves "test" in front.

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TableRow trNew1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tr13);
            TextView textView18 =  new TextView(this);
            textView18.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView18.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
            textView18.setText("Check");
            textView18.setLayoutParams(rowParams2);
            trNew1.addView(textView18,0);

        TextView textView19 = new TextView(this);
        textView19.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView19.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        textView19.setText("Session");
        textView19.setLayoutParams(rowParams2);
        trNew1.addView(textView19,1);

        TextView textView20 = new TextView(this);
        textView20.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView20.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
        textView20.setText("Set");
        textView20.setLayoutParams(rowParams2);
        trNew1.addView(textView20,2);

        TextView textView7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        //TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams)textView7.getLayoutParams();
        rowParams2.span = 6;
        textView7.setLayoutParams(rowParams2);
```

The xml part:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tr13"      
        >

        <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/tl"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:id="@+id/tr4"
        >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Test" /> 
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr"
        >

        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Result image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have no idea why it not follow the sequence and move the test in
>   front.

This is happening because the TableLayout containing the "Test" TextView is already in the layout and the basic addView() method takes this in consideration when adding new views. If you want a different order then use the addView() method that also takes an int representing the position of the child in the parent:

```
// add textView18 as the first child of the parent(initially the TableLayout tl is at position 0)
trNew1.addView(textView18, 0);
// add as the second child(positions are 0 based)
trNew1.addView(textView19, 1);
// add as the third child, at this moment the TableLayout tl will be at position 3
trNew1.addView(textView20, 2);
```

Comment: @micky I'm assuming that is happening because of the nested TableLayout. Check this stripped layout https://gist.github.com/luksprog/db25518609dbe6e767d2 also, also create `TableRow.LayoutParams` instances for **all** views that you add in code(and the width should be MATCH_PARENT, height should be WRAP_CONTENT). Do you plan to add any more rows to the root TableLayout besides the tr13 TableRow?

Comment: this is the header layout, i plan to add dynamically tablerow below this header.

Comment: @micky Did you do what I've asked you above? Do you really need the inner Tablelayout?

Comment: yes i have changed the layout width to match_parent and see my update deign view why i have to use inner tablelayout

Comment: @micky It is working? I've done my own tests and all things are ok with the changes I've said above(of course you also need to remove the 800dp value from the tl Tablelayout). And with your layout you can replicate that design.

Comment: yes it's working now. Between how to set the width for the check,session, set column? :)

Comment: @micky if you're not happy with how stretchColumns works or you have a specific value in mind you'll need to calculate that at runtime by seeing the available width of the TableLayout(or screen if it fills it) subtracting any padding or margins that you may want in the layout and then spreading the rest of the total  width to the columns you want.

Comment: @micky Here's a small sample https://gist.github.com/luksprog/446980e87227cacda9e2 , of course if you use paddings or margins you'll need to take those in consideration as well.

Comment: did you have some sample code like tablelayout inside tablerow programmatically?

Comment: @micky No, but it's not something very hard. If you have problems please post a new question related to what you're trying to do.